# Making the buttons position equal vertically

Tags: html, css

As shown with floats, without bootstrap or any other grid system. What would be the best way to vertically align the buttons?

Forgot to add: And keep the columns equal height, when the window is sized down.

```css
.service {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
}

.service:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="service">
  <h2>Service 1 </h2>
  <p>this is service</p>
  <button>click</button>
</div>
<div class="service">
  <h2>Service 2</h2>
  <p>this is service</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam commodi quidem provident optio natus eaque, eius fuga mollitia nihil a labore recusandae in similique saepe eveniet molestiae nulla illo possimus?</p>
  <button>click</button>
</div>
<div class="service">
  <h2>Service 3</h2>
  <p>this is service</p>
  <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by adding height and relative/absolute positioning. see the code below. Also the same result can be achieved using flexbox.

```css
.service {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    height:330px;
    position:relative;
}

.service:nth-child(2){
    margin: 0 2%;
}
        button {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="service">
        <h2>Service 1 </h2>
        <p>this is service</p>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
        <h2>Service 2</h2>
        <p>this is service</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam commodi quidem provident optio natus eaque, eius fuga mollitia nihil a labore recusandae in similique saepe eveniet molestiae nulla illo possimus?</p>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
        <h2>Service 3</h2>
        <p>this is service</p>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: This looks good, I forgot to add I need the columns' height to adjust when the browser window is sized down in width. (without flexbox)

Comment: For that you can add media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
[codepen](https://codepen.io/wapmastera/pen/MGjPRP)

```css
.content{
    height:330px;
    display:table;
    position:relative;
}
.service {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
}
.service:nth-child(2){
    margin: 0 1%;
}
.service button {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="service">
        <h2>Service 1 </h2>
        <p>this is service</p>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
        <h2>Service 2</h2>
        <p>this is service</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam commodi quidem provident optio natus eaque, eius fuga mollitia nihil a labore recusandae in similique saepe eveniet molestiae nulla illo possimus?</p> 
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
        <h2>Service 3</h2>
        <p>this is service</p>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can manage this:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: Spance-between;
}

.service {
  flex: 1 0 32%;
  display: flex;
  text-align:center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

button {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="service">
    <h2>Service 1 </h2>
    <p>this is service</p>
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="service">
    <h2>Service 2</h2>
    <p>this is service</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam commodi quidem provident optio natus eaque, eius fuga mollitia nihil a labore recusandae in similique saepe eveniet molestiae nulla illo possimus?</p>
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="service">
    <h2>Service 3</h2>
    <p>this is service</p>
    <button>click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```